# What is the best method for avoiding email blacklists in a VPS that has several websites?

Tags: email, email-delivery

We have a powerful VPS currently having various websites. This websites although they do not spam have had their i.p. emails blacklisted in the past? we keep fighting against getting the i.p.. delisted because it otherwise affects all websites email deliverability. It seems too vulnerable that if the I.P. gets blacklisted then everybody loses business not being able to contact their clients. I know large websites have strategies to avoid this, not sure how they do it. I would like to know an experts advice on how to deal with this problem. In summary what are recommended best practices for business email deliverability when depending on one I.P.? or is there such thing as dynamic I.P.s? Open to any options to solve this critical problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

There are many steps you can take to insure that your IP does not get blacklisted in RBL's.

1. You can assign a unique IP for each website and you can assign same unique IP for outgoing mails so all the domains will not be affected if IP gets blacklisted.
2. Make sure you have enabled SMTP authentication for all the domains.
3. You can set SPF records for all the websites. You can create an SPF record from below URL.
   http://www.spfwizard.net/
4. Create Domainkey (DKIM)
5. Use strong password for email accounts as weak password are more prone to get compromised.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 6. Use the service of an email provider like MailChimp, SendGrid or other, to avoid dealing with all the work related to clean delivery.